# What is the probability that a ﬁve-card poker hand contains cards of ﬁve different kinds?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The textbook also states the following:

> There are $13$ different kinds of cards, with four cards of each kind.
>   (Among the terms commonly used instead of “kind” are “rank,” “face
>   value,” “denomination,” and “value.”) These kinds are twos, threes,
>   fours, fives, sixes, sevens, eights, nines, tens, jacks, queens,
>   kings, and aces. There are also four suits: spades, clubs, hearts, and
>   diamonds, each containing 13 cards, with one card of each kind in a
>   suit.

which describes it what it means by a 'kind'.

So far I did the following:

$$\Large\frac{\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

I think I am missing something in the numerator however. Maybe $\binom{47}{5}$? But I am not sure how to justify it.

Edit: Had to edit the question, so if somebody already started answering please check it.

Comment: The reason I feel like it may be incomplete is because 0.000495 is a very low probability and I would have suspected it to be higher.

Comment: I was too hasty.  Your suspicion is justified.

Comment: Incidentally, the expression $\frac{\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$ represents the probability of getting $5$ different cards all in a chosen suit (say, spades). The probability of getting a flush is therefore $4\frac{\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}} = 4(0.000495) = 0.00198$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We must select five of the $13$ kinds, which can be done in $\binom{13}{5}$ ways.  For each of the five kinds we can select, there are four suits from which we can select a card of that kind.  Hence, the number of ways we can select a hand in which each card is of a different kind is 
$$\binom{13}{5} \cdot 4^5$$
Hence, the probability that a five card poker hand contains cards of five different kinds is 
$$\frac{\binom{13}{5} \cdot 4^5}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

Comment: So why 4^5 instead of a combinatorial?

Comment: Since we are selecting one suit from each kind, we have $\binom{4}{1} = 4$ choices for the suit.

Comment: What do you mean by "suit" (I am a non-native speaker and I do not understand what you actually mean by the word "suit")? Yet, I understand your reasoning.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer  The four suits in a deck of cards are hearts, diamonds, spades, and clubs.  You wrote a nice alternative argument.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for your explanation and your compliment. Yet, I think that a fully combinatorial argument, like yours, is better in general, because intuitive and systematic.

Answer (score 3):

You have $52$ choices for the first card. It remains $52-4$ cards of a different kind for the second one, $52-4\cdot2$ for the third, $52-4\cdot 3$ for the fourth and $52-4\cdot 4$ for the fifth. It gives

$$(52-4\cdot 0)(52-4\cdot 1)(52-4\cdot 2)(52-4\cdot 3)(52-4\cdot 4)$$

But you have to discount the permutations of $5$ cards, that is $5!$. It gives

$$\frac{(52-4\cdot 0)(52-4\cdot 1)(52-4\cdot 2)(52-4\cdot 3)(52-4\cdot 4)}{5!}$$

possibilities. The probability is then

$$\frac{\frac{(52-4\cdot 0)(52-4\cdot 1)(52-4\cdot 2)(52-4\cdot 3)(52-4\cdot 4)}{5!}}{52\choose 5}\approx 0.507$$

Comment: What am I doing wrong? `(52-(4*0))*(52-(4*1))*(52-(4*2))*(52-(4*3))*(52-(4*4))` = `(52*48*44*40*36)` = `158146560`.  `5!` = `(120)`. `(52/5)` = `(10.4)`.  `(158146560/120)/10.4` = `126720`.

Comment: It isn't $52/5$, it is $52\choose 5$, which is read `52 choose 5` (you can look at [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) ). The definition is ${52\choose 5}=\frac{52!}{5!(52-5)!}$.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. I now get `0.50708283313`

Answer (score 2):

Pr = [Choose ranks * Choose suit for each chosen rank ] / [Choose any 5 cards]

= $\dfrac{\dbinom{13}5{\dbinom41}^5}{\dbinom{52}5}$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the first card dealt is an Ace. Then of the 51 cards remaining in the deck, 3 are Aces, 48 are not Aces. From these 51 cards, and for our second deal, we require one card from out of the 48 cards that are not Aces. The chance for this event to occur is 48/51.
Assuming the second card dealt is not an Ace, we now have 50 cards in the deck of which 3 are Aces and 3 have the same face value as the second card just dealt. There remain 50-(3+3)=50-6=44 cards which have different face values from the first two cards dealt, and we require one card from these 44 for our next deal. The chance for this event to occur is 44/50.
Proceeding in this way, the probability we are seeking is given by
(48/51)*(44/50)*(40/49)*(36/48) which is approximately .5071
This is the correct answer, and appears in the book "An Introduction To Probability" by William Feller, in the section titled 'Subpopulations And Partitions'.