# Probability that a five-card poker hand contains cards of different kind?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I got a question similar to this on searching.
[Here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540925/what-is-the-probability-that-a-%EF%AC%81ve-card-poker-hand-contains-cards-of-%EF%AC%81ve-differe)

The correct answer is:
$\frac{\binom{13}{5} \cdot 4^5}{\binom{52}{5}}$

However, I tried this:
$ \Large\frac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}\binom{11}{1}\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{1} \cdot 4^5}{\binom{52}{5}} $

I see that $\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}\binom{11}{1}\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{1}$ equals $\frac{13!}{8!}$ which means this multiplication generates a permutation and needs to be divided by $5!$.
So, although I know this solution isn't right, I'm not entirely sure why it is wrong either. Why isn't the solution I tried working according to the product rule?

Comment: The correct probability should be $\frac{\binom{13}{5} \cdot 4^5}{\binom{52}{5}}$ (not $\binom{13}{5} \cdot 4^5$):

Comment: Oh yes those are the number of favorable cases. Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of five binomials in your attempt counts the number of ways to select five ranks *with order* – i.e. your answer treats $9,6,4,8,5$ as different from $4,5,6,8,9$. However, poker hands do not have order, and the same ranks of cards will lead to the same $4^5$ associated hands. Hence you have overcounted by $5!$, which is the factor between your answer and the correct one.

Comment: This makes sense yes. Can't believe I overlooked it. Thanks